How to create a same polkadot wallet from mnemonic like trustwallet using @polkadot/keyring?
I have to create a wallet of polkadot like trustwallet. I tried to create a wallet with "type: ed25519" but it also return different address.
Here is the trust wallet configuration
  {
    "id": "polkadot",
    "name": "Polkadot",
    "coinId": 354,
    "symbol": "DOT",
    "decimals": 10,
    "blockchain": "Polkadot",
    "derivation": [
      {
        "path": "m/44'/354'/0'/0'/0'"
      }
    ],
    "curve": "ed25519",
    "publicKeyType": "ed25519",
    "addressHasher": "keccak256",
    "ss58Prefix": 0,
}



I solved the issues like this.
below is code for create a wallet for specific derivePath
import {mnemonicToSeed} from 'bip39';
import {derivePath} from 'ed25519-hd-key';
import {Keyring} from '@polkadot/keyring';

const createPolkadotWallet = async mnemonic => {
  try {
    const seed = await mnemonicToSeed(mnemonic);
    const privateKey = derivePath("m/44'/354'/0'/0'/0'", seed).key;
    const keyring = new Keyring({ss58Format: 0});
    const keypair = keyring.addFromSeed(privateKey);
    return {
      address: keypair.address,
      privateKey: privateKey?.toString('hex'),
    };
  } catch (e) {
    console.error('Error in createPolkadotWallet', e);
    throw e;
  }
};

